# How to calculate coverage on push and add comment in PR?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have build workflow on push where I have a lot of steps, also here I calculate code coverage and I even upload artifact with jacoco. Right now I want to add PR comment with coverage on pull request. I don't want to repeat the same steps, I only need to comment with coverage on pull request. Do you know how to achieve that?

I tried to download artifact with  jacoco but it is on other workflow so I don't have access to this. Also my build step  on push works about 45 minutes so the step with comment needs to be executed after completed on push build.